# get the id starting with

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker in a div with class pickergroup, I have 3 datepicker in my page, and this is why I use a group and different names

```
<div class="pickergroup">
     <input type="text" name="day1" id="day1"/> / 
     <input type="text" name="month1" id="month1"/> / 
     <input type="text" name="year1" id="year1"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="date1" name="date1"/>  
     <div id="datepicker1" name="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

In my jquery I want to detect when clicking the id wich starts with "datepicker", I guess something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pickergroup id^="datepicker"', function() {
  $(".pickergroup").find('[id^="datepicker"]').datepicker({
      //my datepicker code
  });
});
```

but this is not correct.

how can I do it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about JQuery's syntax, but in CSS attribute selectors look like this:  `[id^="datepicker"]`

Comment: `'.pickergroup id^="datepicker"'` to `'.pickergroup [id^="datepicker"']` .... it's always better to use class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how you're selecting the element inside of the event handler.

```
$(".pickergroup").find('[id^="datepicker"]')
```

means "find all elements with the class of `pickergroup`. Find all of their *children* which have an ID starting with `datepicker`." Instead, you want to use `this` and fix your selector from

```
.pickergroup id^="datepicker"
```

to

```
.pickergroup [id^="datepicker"]
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.pickergroup [id^="datepicker"]', function() {
  var $this = $(this); // The div that was clicked
  console.log($this.text());
});
```

```css
.pickergroup div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pickergroup">
  <div id="datepicker1">A</div>
</div>
<div class="pickergroup">
  <div id="datepicker2">B</div>
</div>
<div class="pickergroup">
  <div id="datepicker3">C</div>
</div>
<div class="pickergroup">
  <div id="can-t-click-me">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".pickergroup").find('[id^="datepicker"]')` should work just fine given the structure of the HTML. The real issues were that the OP omitted the brackets around the attribute selector and he used a `div`, rather than an `input` for the datepicker.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It would work fine *if* they want to modify every datepicker when the click on just one. I assume they don't want to do that so using `this` is the right way to access the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the datepicker element needs to be an input. And remember, ID's are unique. If you using starts with selector, it is ok. But please dont get confusing with this.
Second, why need seperate fields? You could use one datepicker, decide the format you want to display and you could also parse the returned value from the datepicker in the format you need/want. Please have a look at the documentation.

Comment: *"First of all, the datepicker element needs to be an input"* - Which date picker are you talking about? What is your reference?

Comment: @TJ I am talking about the jQuery UI datepicker widget, as you could guess on the question topic.

Comment: From: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ *"The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. "*

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, so it needs to be an input field, not a div container as we could see in the question's code.

Comment: I know, I'm concurring with you and providing a reference for @TJ

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's basic info. Once you click learn more, and learn more about it,  then no, it [does not need to be an input](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#example-0). BTW the OP hasn't specified which datepicker he is using.